# Two different collection views getting the item count of the other

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an app with 2 different arrays that usually have 2 different item counts. For some reason the first collection view is getting the item count of the second collection view unless I get rid of the second collection view.

My code:

```html
<script src="https://pastebin.com/embed_js/NAtgb3kp"></script>
```

Comment: Do not post a link to your code. [Edit] your question and copy and paste relevant code into your question.

Comment: There is a possibility that songsViewCollectionView is not set, check your IBOutlets, debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps: 
 1. say your collection are

```
var albumsViewCollectionView, songsViewCollectionView : UICollectionView!
```

2. Register the nib files for your 2 collectionviews
3. your collectionview datasource method

   ```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   if collectionview == albumsViewCollectionView {
      return albumCount
   }
   else if  collectionview == songsViewCollectionView {
     return songsCount
   }

   return 0
   }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   if collectionView == albumsViewCollectionView {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AlbumsViewCollectionView", for: indexPath) as! AlbumsViewCollectionView
       return cell

   }
   else if collectionView == songsViewCollectionView {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SongsViewCollectionView", for: indexPath) as! SongsViewCollectionView

       return cell

   }

   return UICollectionViewCell()

   }
   ```